# Cypress stubbing with .intercept() and fixture

Tags: cypress

I am trying to stub a response from an API. Following the Cypress docs, I landed on this:

```js
cy.intercept('GET', '/v1/answers', { fixture: 'answers.json' }).as(
  'getAnswers'
)

cy.wait('@getAnswers').then(console.log)
```

The `console.log` yields the correct response.

However the UI component does not appear to consume this data. Instead the data in the component comes back as empty. Is there something I am missing on the correct usage of intercept and fixtures in Cypress?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having this issue. In the Cypress app's browser console I noticed a CORS error and needed to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

```js
cy.intercept('GET', '/v1/answers', {
  fixture: 'answers.json',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',  // <== This fixed it 
  },
}).as('getAnswers')
```

:)